# How to set min/max constraints in Prisma model (PostgreSQL)

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, orm, prisma

I'm wondering if its possible to check if age is +18 before adding user into the database. I know that I can check that runtime on REST endpoints but this approach should be little bit more secure(?). Maybe its somehow possible to add raw SQL with this check to my migrations?
Its my first time using relational database in real apps, in MongoDb with mongoose all i had to do was to define `age: { type: number, min: 18, max: 99 }` in schema

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id              Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name            String   @unique @db.VarChar(40)
  email           String   @unique @db.VarChar(120)
  age             Int      // check if age is +18 here
}
```

Comment: Check constraints are an [open issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3388) but the docs cover this extensively [Data validation with CHECK constraints (PostgreSQL)](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/advanced-database-tasks/data-validation/postgresql)

Comment: or the [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) documentation

Comment: @pilchard Okay I found the guide you've sent in the meantime, turned out I didn't really understood what migrations are. I thought that once i change something in migration i'll have to rewrite it after every next schema change, but thanks god its working well. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Prisma doesn't support any constraints such as `min` or `max`

It's possible to manually check it in your code, but value still can be changed in the DB to any possible `int` value